# How parse an Azure URI into key-value pairs in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, dictionary, parsing

Azure URIs which uniquely identify an Azure resource have this format.

/subscription/nameofsub/resourcegroup/nameofgroup/resource/nameofresource.

From the example above you can see that it follows the format of /key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3

What would be a good way to take that URI string and turn it into a dictionary or something like a JSON string of key-value pairs in Python3?

Comment: Just curious about the use case of parsing this URI. Can you please describe that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a bit of string manipluation, though not very elegantly:

```
az = "/subscription/nameofsub/resourcegroup/nameofgroup/resource/nameofresource"
az1 = az.split('/')[1:]
az_dict = {}
for k,v in zip(az1[::2],az1[1::2]):
    az_dict[k]=v
az_dict
```

Output:

```
{'subscription': 'nameofsub',
 'resourcegroup': 'nameofgroup',
 'resource': 'nameofresource'}
```